# Different Functions which make inequality into equality ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**EDIT:** This question is related to the theorem from ODE book:
**Theorem:** Suppose $f, g ∈ C(U,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and let $f$ be locally Lipschitz continuous in the second argument, uniformly with respect to the first. If $x(t)$
and $y(t)$ are respective solutions of the IVPs
$\dot{x} = f(t, x), \: x(t_0) = x_0$
and $\dot{y} = g(t, y), \: y(t_0) = y_0,$
then
$$|x(t) − y(t)| ≤ |x_0 − y_0| e^{L|t−t_0|} +
\frac{M}L
(e^{L|t−t_0|} − 1),$$
where
$$L = \sup_{
(t,x)\ne(t,y)∈V}
\frac{|f(t, x) − f(t, y)|}{
|x − y|}
, \: M = \sup_{
(t,x)∈V} |f(t, x) − g(t, x)|,$$
with $V ⊂ U$ some set containing the graphs of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

**QUESTION:** Find different functions $f(t, x) = f(x)$ and $g(t, x) = g(x)$
such that the inequality $$|x(t) − y(t)| ≤ |x_0 − y_0| e^{L|t−t_0|} +
\frac{M}L
(e^{L|t−t_0|} − 1),$$
becomes an equality.

I have tried few functions but always I get stuck at same $f=g$ or that $g=M$

Comment: How is this related to differential equations? Also, what do $x(t), y(t)$ refer to?, what are $x_0,y_0,t_0$? Please be more clear.

Comment: I have edited my question with more explanation.

Comment: I doubt you will be able to find explicit answers in anything but the linear case